# Nmap shows 554 and 7070 open on EVERY machine even when they are closed/filtered

Tags: port, scanner, nmap

Every single machine I scan shows port 7070 and port 554 as open regardless if the ports are closed/filtered. 
It will still show those two ports as open even if the target is offline (and the scan is run without ping test).

Nmap tests all other ports fine and reports the expected states, it's just these 2 ports.

Comment: Could you post the command line parameters that you use? Could you also post the output of `nmap -n -Pn -sS -p554,7070 --packet-trace --reason <targets>`?

Comment: Normally I'd use one of the pre-defined profiles in Zenmap f.e. nmap -T4 -A -v -Pn 75.27.30.143

Here's a pastebin of a few example targets which shouldn't have either port open.
http://pastebin.com/g57DJvRu

Comment: Since you're not in the same LAN as those machines, I guess that some gateway in between intercepts the packets on ports 554 and 7070.  If I'm not mistaken you can find this out with `traceroute -n -T -p554 75.27.30.143`.

Comment: This worked, turns out my router is intercepting packets for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

Certain routers intercept traffic on these ports, I can confirm that the BT Homehub does.  I can telnet any_random_ip 7070 and get a connection.

Comment: what is the purpose? is any service running on those ports?

Answer (score 1):

Various routers (Verizon FiOS, BT Home Hub, Apple Airport Extreme, ...) always show `*:554` and `*:7070` as open for some reason.

[Hackerific » False positive TCP ports!](https://hackerific.net/2016/03/20/false-positive-tcp-ports/)